# How to get a model attribute after fetch operation

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am a newbie in backbone . I wanted to know when i do the following operation how i can get the model fetched values.

For example if i do something like following

```
this.model.fetch();
```

and i want to get a value for example

```
this.model.get("VALUE");
```

How i can make sure i get the right value which is fetched right now from the server. I am trying to do something like following but ofcourse this.model is not recognized inside the complete block.

```
    this.model.fetch().complete(function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem("VALUE", this.model.get("VALUE"));
    });
```

I am stuck here. Does anybody have any ideas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I see two options: 1. just get rid of the complete block and use the functions separately.

```
this.model.fetch();
var value = this.model.get('value');
//or, if you want all of the values
// var values = this.model.toJSON();
// values.value -> the specific value
```

And I'm not very experienced with local storage, but why are you fetching a value and then setting it to local storage?

Or, 2. You could put your inner statements in a function, and bind it to the `this`:

```
initialize: function () {
    _.bind('setItem', this);
},
setItem: function() {
    // assuming this code works
    window.localStorage.setItem("VALUE", this.model.get("VALUE"));
}
// elsewhere, and not familiar with complete, so I'm not certain how this works
this.model.fetch().complete(setItem);
```

Comment: Actually I just a need a value from the model currently fetched and manipulate a view. I can simply make a server call and feth this value but i don't want to make another call for just a value which i know is already fetched right now